# Mysql container always restart itself

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, containers

i made container from image mysql, but the container cant run the container. always restart itself

my docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: mysql 
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes: 
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
            MSYQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
            SERVICE_TAG: dev
            SERVICES_NAME: mysql
        networks: 
            - laravel
```

when i tried command `docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps mysql` i got this

```
2020-08-19T02:55:23.433654365Z 2020-08-19 02:55:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-19T02:55:23.806507100Z 2020-08-19 02:55:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-08-19T02:55:23.829003854Z 2020-08-19 02:55:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-19T02:55:24.171193704Z 2020-08-19 02:55:24+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
2020-08-19T02:55:24.171719392Z  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
2020-08-19T02:55:29.345542908Z 2020-08-19 02:55:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-19T02:55:29.728781351Z 2020-08-19 02:55:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-08-19T02:55:29.763193498Z 2020-08-19 02:55:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2020-08-19T02:55:30.181369167Z 2020-08-19 02:55:30+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
2020-08-19T02:55:30.181429655Z  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

If the container fails, but its **[restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy)** is `unless-stopped`... It will restart:

> Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.

Note that:

> A restart policy only takes effect after a container starts successfully. In this case, starting successfully means that the container is up for at least 10 seconds and Docker has started monitoring it.

So in your case, that should not apply (since the log timestamps shows only a few seconds), but still, for testing, you could check if setting restart to `no` would avoid that loop.